# double-notification: once per tag

Tags: bug, tags, subscription

If you subscribed to several tags, and there is a new question which belongs to more than one tag at once, you'll receive as many emails as the tags, e'g you subscribed to tags A, B, C, D and the question about C, D, E, F you'll receive two messages.

Please combine the email so I get at most one email per post.